# How to inflate custom layout in runtime while avoiding redundant layout in the view hierarchy - Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

In general, I want to know how should I inflate custom layout defined in XML at runtime without having a redundant layout in my views hierarchy.

Now, in particular:

I have a custom layout which is declared in an xml, `my_relative_layout.xml` and its root element is a RelativeLayout.
I have also defined a class which extends RelativeLayout called `MyRelativeLayout.java`.

How can I inflate `my_relative_layout.xml` in my `MyRelativeLayout.java` in a way that I won't have a redundant RelativeLayout in the hierarchy.

I tried using `<merge>`  - it caused that all the root element attributes in `my_relative_layout.xml` didn't affect so my layout content was messed up.

I also tried to declare my custom layout class as the root element in `my_relative_layout.xml`, but got inflation exception (i tried both setting root element to null or this, while inflating the xml in `MyRelativeLayout.java` - with true or false in attach to root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `<merge>` tag.
Note that you must set all the `RelativeLayout` layout params at runtime.